# JUnit Test for adding 5 Seconds to Timestamp: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [object]

Tags: java, testing, junit

I wrote a method updating a timestamp for an object. It works fine, the value gets updated the way it is supposed to. However, I can't get the unit test to work.

Cake has a value inspectiondate that is initialised with the timestamp of when the object is first created.

This is my method:

```
public static void updateInspectionDate(Cake cakeToBeUpdated){ 
        cakeToBeUpdated.setInspectDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
```

This is my test(tried a couple of ways of testing it, this is my current version), the obejct is already created in the test class:

```
@Test 
    void updateInspectionDateTest(Cake apple) throws InterruptedException {
        Calendar newInspectionDate = Calendar.getInstance(); //create new date that`s current inspection date + 5 seconds
        newInspectionDate.setTime(apple.getInspectiondate());
        newInspectionDate.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5); //wait 5 seconds
        updateInspectionDate(apple); //inspection date of apple will be updated to 5 seconds after it was inserted

        assertEquals( newInspectionDate.getTime(), apple.getInspectiondate());
    }
```

This is the error I'm getting:

org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [Cake arg0] in method [void CakeTest.updateInspectionDate(Cake) throws java.lang.InterruptedException].

So what exactly is going wrong and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You've created a test method having a parameter. Usually, tests are not having parameters. Only if they are executed by a parameterized run (run same method for multiple values).

Your test method should be like `void updateInspectionDateTest()`. But please think about a more meaningful name and not just the same as it should test.

Comment: thank you, that solved the problem!